# Making the background color of button change and persist after a click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-view, android-adapter

I have a ListFragment that contains a Button in every list item. When the Button is clicked, the colour of the Button changes (using a Drawable xml resource). Though the color of the Button changes during the click event, its color changes back to its default value after the event, i.e the color change is momentarily observable during the click and not afterwards. What I'd really like to happen is for the color change to persist after the event fires.

I have tried an approach to manipulate item views via the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method of the ListFragment's custom adapter (a SimpleAdapter in my case) where I could store positions of the items and persist the background state of every Button. However I would like to replicate this solution using selectors.

I have two Drawable resources setting colours for the pressed and clicked states of each Button as well the selector resource that manages those states.

Here is my drawable resource that manipulates color states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/clicked_drawable" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/clicked_drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unclicked_drawable" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And the two resources that contain the different colours, clicked_drawable.xml & unclicked_drawable.xml, in order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid
         android:color="#F08080"
     /> 
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#FFB00F"
    />  
</shape>
```

And the layout file for the ListFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" 
>

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    /> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label" 
            android:gravity="start"

        />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"

        />

     </LinearLayout>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/button"
         android:layout_margin="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_drawable"

      />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I am unable to solve this and any direction, guidance or a solution will be most appreciated.

Comment: you need to do it programatically\

Comment: You should do it programatically , like add a tag for your button , and on different tags set button's Background to something different

Comment: if its a listfragment then you need to apply the color change in your getview method of your adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to your `Adapter` class' `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public void getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

    final Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clicked_drawable);

            .....
            .....

    }

....
....

}
```

Try this. It will work.

Comment: Yes, this was useful. However a point to note - since the ListView recycles its elements, the buttons that were previously clicked may lose their background state upon scrolling. But this issue was not really part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="test" />
```

And make your selector like this, set all the states to the same drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```